# How to show a widget on button click of another widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

My question is simple, I am trying to open a child window within the main window. I took help of all of the answers so this question is not a duplicate. My child window comes for some time and then disappears automatically.

```
import random
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic


class SubWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(SubWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        label = QLabel("Sub Window",  self)
        label.setGeometry(0, 0, 20, 10)
        self.show()


class pro(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(pro, self).__init__(parent)


        self.acceptDrops()

        self.x = 200
        self.y = 200
        self.width = 800
        self.length = 800

        self.setGeometry(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.length)
        self.setWindowTitle("PA")

        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('p_bg.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.setGeometry(0, 0, 1100, 1000)

        self.initgui()

    def register_system(self):
        opener = SubWindow()
        opener.show()

    def initgui(self):

        self.btn_log = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_log.setGeometry(440, 250, 150, 30)
        self.btn_log.setText("         Login         ")
        self.btn_log.adjustSize()

        self.btn_sign = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_sign.setGeometry(440, 300, 150, 30)
        self.btn_sign.setText("       Register       ")
        self.btn_sign.adjustSize()
        self.btn_sign.clicked.connect(self.register_system)

        self.welcome = QLabel("Arial font", self)
        self.welcome.setText("Welcome")
        self.welcome.setGeometry(410, 100, 200, 30)
        self.welcome.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent;")
        self.welcome.setFont(QFont("Arial", 30))

        self.show()

def window():

    apk = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = pro()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(apk.exec_())
window()
```

I took help to make a child window from here:https://www.codersarts.com/post/multiple-windows-in-pyqt5-codersarts , I used type 2 resource in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason probably is that the variable `opener` has scope within the `register_system` method only; it is getting deleted after the method exits, you can modify the code either to create the variable as an attribute to the class object using `self` and then show the widget like this:

```py
    def register_system(self):
        self.opener = SubWindow()
        self.opener.show()
```

Or, you can just create a variable `opener` at global scope, then use the global variable to assign and show the widget:

```py
# imports
opener = None
class SubWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
    
    #Rest of the code

class pro(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    # Rest of the code

    def register_system(self):
        global opener
        opener = SubWindow()
        opener.show()

    # Rest of the code
```

On a side note, you should always use layout for the widgets in PyQt application, you can take a look at [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Comment: @Iamnew that doesn't really matter, after all, we are here to help others and get help from others.